# Is geometric distribution part of Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

Is geometric distribution a type of Bernoulli distribution? But I remember geometric distribution has mean $1/p$ not matching the table here.
[image]

Comment: "*Is geometric distribution a type of Bernoulli distribution?*" Not really.

Comment: Likely the “PMF” formula in that table was confusing you. A Bernoulli random variable $X$ can only take one of two values, 0 or 1, and $P[X=1]=p, P[X=0]=1-p$.

Comment: The distributions are related but not the same. The number of Bernoulli trials until there is a failure has geometric distribution, for example.